# GridView not displaying data that has been retrieved asynchronously via a CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, async-await

What I am attempting to do is retrieve a collection of Files (asynchronously) and display then in a GridView grouped by the First Letter of the file name.

For example, if a file is called “Pic” this would be displayed under a column within the title “P”.

Below is some code from my View Model:

```
public ObservableCollection<File> Files { get; set; }
public List<FileCategory> Items { get; set; }
private FileRepository _fileRepository;
public MoviesPageViewModel()
{
        _fileRepository = new FileRepository();
        this.Construct();
        var filesByCategories = Files.GroupBy(x => x.Title[0].ToString())
            .Select(x => new FileCategory { Title = x.Key, Items = new ObservableCollection<File>(x)});
        Items = filesByCategories.ToList();
}  
private async void Construct()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
        IList _files = await _fileRepository.GetFiles();
        foreach (File file in _files)
        {
            Files.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Here is the CollectionViewSource from the View

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items"/>
```

And the GridView from the same View (minus the templates)

```
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
    Margin="116,0,40,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}">
```

When I build and run, I get nothing on the screen. However, I know that the code is close to working because:

1. Removing the call to Construct() in the constructor and replacing it 
   with some code to hardcode a few File objects into the Files
   collection produces the desired output.
2. Removing the use of the CollectionViewSource and binding the
       GridView directly to the Files collection (and still using the async
       code) presents the collection on screen, but of course they are not
       filtered as this bypases the use of Items (and binding the GridView
       to Items produces no result either)

I believe that this could be because my Items collection does not have any change notification so the collection is not updading to screen as the async call is carrying on after the initial load.

Does anybody know why this could be happening and/or offer any advice on fixes?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by making a few changes.

I made the Items collection into an ObservableCollection and then moved the linq query and adding the query results to the async Construct method.

This feels quite messy but it works for now. Thanks all!

Comment: As-is, you're doing the linq query after you started Construct, but hasn't completed yet. If you want to keep the query outside of Construct, you'll want it to return Task instead of void and then ContinueWith the query (can't await since ctor) or make a new async wrapper method that does await Construct() then does the query. The latter is preferable since the continuation needs to happen on the UI thread I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `CollectionViewSource` is bound to the `Items` collection and you are adding items to the `Files` collection

Either change your code to add to `Items` or change your XAML to point to `Files`

You may need to also invoke the Add operation

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer.
I believe that the CollectionViewSource should point to Items. As you can see in the constructor for MoviesPageViewModel, I am assigning the filesByCategories linq result which contains a group of key/Items collections. 
If I hardcode some File objects into the Files collection instead of calling the async code, the UI renders properly (just with the hard coded values)

Comment: LINQ to Objects isn't "live" - you don't get an observable collection out of LINQ, so updates won't flow through to the control.